# Implementing a Draft Ticker for my football game---Best performance in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, animation, storyboard

OK, I am implementing a draft ticker that scrolls along the bottom of the screen in my WPF Football Game Project.  I am working on sorting out the best method for doing this, and would like some help.  I have the ticker working as you can see in this video:
https://slack-files.com/T0P56UMQ8-F23G69M5Y-6d1577a07d

Currently I am adding a new Image and TextBlock for each pick, which I know is going to slow down performance once it gets up to 32 of each of those scrolling.  I am wondering if there is a better solution, ie, can I add these objects to a type of Observable Collection and have them added dynamically once the pick happens and the new information gets added to the collection?  Is there a way to create a single object with all the images and textblocks combined together as one object?

Wondering what the best implementation of this would be for performance purposes.  I clearly know I could simply continue dynamically adding images and textblocks to the animated storyboard, but I am wondering if there is a more effective method of doing this?

Comment: Put your example video on youtube or make a gif or something, most of us won't download a direct file from here. If I could see the concept you're after then recommendations could be made, however this question still falls in the category of "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion Based" so it may get closed.

Comment: The concept I am after is a scrolling ticker at the bottom of the screen, like you would see while watching the draft. I have that part working, but for what I'm trying to implement I don't think my current approach is the best way to do it, which is why I'm trying to get a better method